# How do I embed HTML entities in text in a Hoplon page?

Tags: clojurescript, hoplon

I'm trying to render HTML entities in Hoplon using the following:

`(a :href "#" :class "deck-prev-link" :title "Previous" "&#8592;")`

But instead of an arrow, it's displaying the literal `&#8592;` in the rendered page.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try to paste "←" itself in source code?

Comment: For ClojureScript uses, see also [ClojureScript and HTML entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408377/clojurescript-and-html-entities) which has [an answer which shows how to unescape HTML entities using the Google Closure library](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23353583/109618).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So in case anyone is wondering, the answer is to either paste the "←" directly into the string like this:

`(a :href "#" :class "deck-prev-link" :title "Previous" "←")`

or to use the unicode escape in the string like this:

`(a :href "#" :class "deck-prev-link" :title "Previous" "\u2190")`

I found the unicode decimal code point for the leftward arrow here: [List of XML and HTML Character Entity References](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).