# Enlive and &mdash;

Tags: html, clojure, enlive

Trying to add an & mdash; between two divs using Enlive but

```
           {:tag :span,
             :attrs {:class "mdash"},
             :content "&mdash;"}
```

just returns the actual text & mdash; instead of drawing a —

Thoughts?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408377/clojurescript-and-html-entities

Comment: thanks moogs.  good find

Answer (score 0):

Enlive will escape `&` for ordinary `(content some-string)`, because that's a sane default.

To set raw HTML content and escaped characters, use `html-content`, which uses `html-snippet` under the hood.

**Example**

```
(html/html-snippet "&mdash;<p>hello</p>")

("—" {:tag :p,
      :attrs nil, 
      :content ("hello")})
```